# How to find text on webview then highlight it?

Tags: java, android, webview, find

Im successfully learn how to find a text on webview and highlight it using this code.

```
webview.findAllAsync(string);
```

And it perfectly work, I want to use it to trigger someting like If webview found a text, then it will display a toast "found"

How to make this happend is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#setFindListener(android.webkit.WebView.FindListener)

This listener is helpful.

You can use below code:

```
 webView.setFindListener(
      new WebView.FindListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFindResultReceived(int i, int i1, boolean b) {

               Toast.makeText(context, "Found "+i1+" results" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
          });
                                
        webView.findAllAsync("act");
```